# Share data between angular js and angular app

Tags: angular, angularjs

I have two applications

1. http://localhost/testsite (Angular js application)
2. http://localhost:4200 (Angular application)

I want to share data from angular js application to angular application. Please help me to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use local storage or save data into a file and read in the angular app by path of data.

https://medium.com/@anooprvarrier/angular-reading-data-from-json-file-using-httpclient-3c46ba1aaf22

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.